# memoizing state of array of objects

Tags: reactjs

i have a react state which is array of objects (containing data of child component), and the child component can update the data (lift up the state), but whenever it does all of the other child components will get re rendered, so i want to add memoization but problem is that i pass only the object of state's array to each component so it won't work, for better understanding here is the code

state declaration:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(() =>
  Array.from({length: DATA_SIZE}, (_,idx) => ({
    values: [],
    id: -1 * (idx + 1) // all of the real ids start from 0
  }))
);
```

and there is usage

```
    {data.map((val) => {
      return <DataForm {...val} />;
    })}
```

now what i am saying is that i can uplift the state (change "values" or "id" prop) from DataForm and all of the other `DataForm` components will get rerendered even though their props did not change even if i add `React.memo` because  "values" is array, so i want to add memoization for each "data" object but i am not sure how because i guess `useMemo` won't help me here.

Comment: Do you have any problems with performance? There's nothing wrong with rerendering by itself. Don't do premature optimization.

Comment: Try adding a `key` prop to the children being rendered. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: @paolostyle yeah you have good point but if i have textarea or input inside dataform and i have certain amount of dataforms on every keystroke is it a good idea to rerender all of them?

Comment: @smac89 yeah but what do i add as a key

Comment: Ideally, you don't want to use the index as the key. I think the name of each field would make sense.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take a look at Formik. You'll only spend time writing your form logic, instead of the dealing with the mechanic of the inputs. https://formik.org/docs/overview

Comment: @Iliaaaa well, it depends. If the form lags, then you should address it. If it doesn't then don't. Simple as that.

Comment: @KevinGilbert agreed on Formik recommendation although it will most likely make their form even laggier; it has great development experience but it also rerenders almost everything by default. If you really need high performance I'd recommend react-hook-form

Comment: ...or [react-final-form](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/getting-started). To answer your question about what to use as key. In this case, you can use the index of the items simply because the list is static.

Comment: i can use index as key but react already does that for me so what difference would it make, i mean index never changes anyway, i heard form manager suggestions but my main point is about concept, as @paolostyle mentioned, it may not lag on 3 dataform but i assume it may lag on 50, my main point is that if i add react-hook-form and update array through it, would it not update other comps (even though i have not looked into react-hook-form deeply, i would believe no, so if i need to do this i guess my best bet is to manually write diffing inside React.memo ?

Comment: react-hook-form uses uncontrolled components so the approach is completely different from how you generally handle forms, that's how they can achieve such good performance.